# JSF error : property not found

Tags: jsf

I am following some basic tutorials on jsf, and have the following code in a bean names `userData`

```
@ManagedBean(name="userData", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class userData implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String welcomeMessage;

    private String selectedCountry = "United Kingdom";
    private static Map<String, String> countries;

    static
    {
        countries = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        countries.put("en", "United Kingdom");
        countries.put("fr","French");
        countries.put("de","Germany");
    }

    public void localeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e)
    {
        selectedCountry = e.getNewValue().toString();
    }

    public void setSelectedCountry(String selectedCountry)
    {
        this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    }

    public String getSelectedCountry()
    {
        return selectedCountry;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCountries()
    {
        return countries;
    }

    public void userData()
    {
        this.name = "Mario";
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    public String login()
    {
        return "result";
    }

    public String getWelcomeMessage()
    {
        return "hello" + name;
    }
}
```

on the other side in a .xhtml page i have part of the html code as follows:

```
<h:form>
        <h1>
            #{userData.selectedCountry}
        </h1>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userData.selectedCountry}" 
                         onchange="submit()"
                        valueChangeListener="#{userData.localeChanged}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{userData.countries}"/> 
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br/>
        <h1>
            Country Name : 
            <h:outputText id="country" value="#{userData.selectedCountry}"/>
        </h1>
    </h:form>
```

yet when i execute the page on the server the following error is produced:
useBeans.xhtml: Property 'selectedCountry' not found on type userData.
Can someone please highlight what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your class isn't compiled as you expected. Apart of this, I don't know which tutorial you're following, but `eager=true` only works with `@ApplicationScoped` managed beans, otherwise this attribute will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was because I copied a class including serialVersionUID field:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5443351151396868724L;
```

so I had two different classes and objects with the same serialVersionUID and this was the clue of the problem.